# Set frame title as \title or pdftitle

Tags: beamer

I'm preparing a series of `beamer` documents with different `\title`s, and the first slide of each document has the same title as the document `\title`. I want to be able to just change the content of `\title` for each document, and then the title of the first slide will be updated automatically.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Some Title}
  \makeatletter
  \hypersetup{pdftitle=\@title}
  \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Some Title}
frame content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Since the frame title is the same as `\title` and `pdftitle`, is there a way to set the frame title to be the same as `pdftitle` or `\title` without typing it again? I tried

```
\begin{frame}{\@title}
```

Obviously this didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution would be to have `\def\mytitle{Title}`, and then `\hypersetup{pdftitle={\mytitle}}` and `\begin{frame}{\mytitle}` as well as `\title{\mytitle}`.